# how to turn off IntelliJ warning for scala "method with accessor like name is empty-paren"

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

How do I turn off this warning? I like most of the Intellij warnings but not this one.

```
method with accessor like name is empty-paren
```

[image: accessor-like-name]

Comment: Can you show the line causing this message?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This inspection is warning you the method is not following the recommended convention to use parameterless methods whenever there are no parameters and the method have no side effects.

[image]

To disable it in IntelliJ IDEA, go to: *Settings... -> Editor -> Code Style -> Inspections -> Scala -> Method Signature* and uncheck **Method with accessor-like name is empty paren**

Comment: Thank you. I was looking in Settings .. -> Editor -> Code Style -> Scala. Which is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple options: (first is in general for any Intellij setting and will save you so much time)

1. - Do a search everywhere (default shortcuts)

     - Windows/Linux: Double press <kbd>Shift</kbd>
     - Mac: Double press <kbd>⇧</kbd>
   - Ensure you have IDE settings enabled: (Click cog and click On as needed)
     [image]
   - Type in the setting you are searching for like "method with accessor "
   - Turn off the corresponding Inspection.
     [image]
2. - Open Settings (Default shortcuts)

     - Windows/Linux: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>
     - Mac: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>
   - Go to **Editor** -> **Inspections** -> **Scala** -> **Method Signature**
   - Find the inspection required and turn it off.

Answer (score 0):

Intellij inspections seem to assume that any method starting with `get`, `is`, or `to` are accessors and any method starting with `set` or `update` are mutators. If you don't want to outright disable the inspection, you can just avoid using these specific verbs.

Otherwise, see Micho's answer to disable it.

Note: I would add this as a comment on the existing chosen answer but I don't yet have the karma for that.